# Full text index search returns an unexpected result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

When I search `TaxIdentityNumber` using `contains` an unexpected result is returned; the result contains numbers that are not matched to query. For example, I search using `'"5689523657*"'` and get `5681254870`, `5458976235`, etc. as result. I rebuilt the index, but get the same result. What should I try? What did I miss?

The full query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Contractors] [contractor] 
INNER JOIN [ReportDates] [reportDate]
    ON [contractor].[ReportDateId] = [reportDate].[Id] 
LEFT JOIN [Persons] [tempPersons]
    ON [contractor].[PersonId] = [tempPersons].[Id] 
LEFT JOIN [Organizations] [tempOrganiztions]
    ON [contractor].[OrganizationId] = [tempOrganiztions].[Id] 
LEFT JOIN [Organizations] [tempHolding]
    ON [contractor].[HoldingId] = [tempHolding].[Id] 
WHERE
    CONTAINS(([contractor].[TaxIdentityNumber]), '"5689523657*"')
```

Running on SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition. Query to create full text index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG SPFTI;
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Contractors]
(FullName, TaxIdentityNumber, RelatedOrganizationFullName) 
KEY INDEX ContractorPK
ON SPFTI;
```

Comment: How is information in `[TaxIdentityNumber]` stored?

Comment: @cha, it's `nvarchar(max)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [**known issue**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2280126) when using **SQL Server 2008** to search for a number with more than **nine digits**. When using certain word-breakers, the number is stored in its scientific form e.g. `nn5d68952e+009`, leading to false-positive matches. One of the word-breakers affected is the neutral language (lcid 0):

```
-- Result includes nn5d68952e+009
SELECT display_term 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"5689523657*"', 0, 0, 0);
```

A language that does not behave this way is us-english (lcid 1033):

```
-- Result includes nn5689523657
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"5689523657*"', 1033, 0, 0);
```

There are several other workarounds and fixes mentioned in the KB article link above.